# TypeCasting to SubClass in Java

Tags: java, oop, casting

I have to typecast an java object to subclass because need to set a indicator on a method available in the subclass then I am going to set the Super class object in a List.

Do I need to to do anything in between or the indicator as set after typecasting is going to reflect when I get the object out from the List ?

MemRow is the Superclass and MemAttrRow is the Subclass with new property recstat;
The code is below:

```
  MemRow memRow;
   List<MemRow> memRwList;//where the superclass will get added 
   // type cast to subclass memAttrRow and set the recstat
     MemAttrRow memAttrRow = (MemAttrRow) memRow;
     String ind= "A";
     memAttrRow.setRecStat(ind);
  //add superclass to the list
     memRwList.addRow(memRow);
```

Comment: I can't tell what that sentence is supposed to mean, but looking at your code -- no, there's nothing special you have to do.

Comment: Your question is unclear at the moment. Casting doesn't change which object you're referring to, so the change when you call `setRecStat` is still going to be visible later, if that's what you mean. I suggest you try it, and post a [mcve] if you have problems.

Comment: type casting is not the best practice here. What you can do is add a constructor or a setter in the subclass which could initialise the fields from the superclass object. Then you can do `MemAttrRow memAttrRow = new  MemAttrRow (memRow)`

Comment: @JonSkeet I m sorry for long sentences.But yes my question was ll my change be visible later.Thanks!

Comment: You have omitted the most important fact, which is how `memRow` was initialized.  If you did `memRow = new MemRow()` then the downcast is invalid and will throw `ClassCastException`.  You can downcast a reference only if it actually points to a subclass instance.

Comment: @RahulSharma Thanks!...but this is an api object I cant change it at this moment.

Comment: you probably want to initialize that list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything else. Assuming the `memRow` is really an instance of `MemAttrRow`, when you set its property it is going to be preserved during operations like adding the object to a list.

However, it is worth to be mentioned that you need to be sure that the real (runtime) type of an object is `MemAttrRow` before you type cast it or you can get `ClassCastException`.

Comment: To check that it can be cast to a MemAttrRow use the instanceof keyword: if(memRow instanceof MemAttrRow){ //do something } else {//it's not a MemAttrRow... do something else}